# Integrating google sign in, sign in button visibility not changing on UpdateUI method

Tags: android-studio, variables, visibility, sign

I am trying to integrate a google sign in feature for my app. Its mostly working fine and I can sign in ok.
However, when the user is signed in, the sign in buttons visibility is supposed to be false, and then a LinearLayout which includes two text views and a log out button is supposed to become visible.

Here is the code of the main layout activity which has all the text views, buttons etc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/prof_section"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Prof_Pic"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="255dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Display name here"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Display email here"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/SignOut"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Logout"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="159dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="506dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Main Activity file with all the code

```
    private LinearLayout prof_section;
    private LinearLayout LsignIn;
    private Button SignOut;
    private SignInButton SignIn;
    private TextView Name,Email;
    private ImageView Prof_Pic;
    private GoogleApiClient GoogleApiClient;
    private static final int REQ_CODE = 9001;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //setting variables as correct object
        prof_section = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.prof_section);
        SignOut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SignOut);
        SignIn = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        Name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Name);
        Email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Email);
        Prof_Pic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Prof_Pic);

        //register buttons for onclick listener
        SignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        SignOut.setOnClickListener(this);

        //setting linearlayout and button to visible/invisible
        prof_section.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        GoogleSignInOptions SignInOptions = new  GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail  ().build();
        GoogleApiClient = new   GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this,this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_  SIGN_IN_API,SignInOptions).build();

    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                SignIn();
                break;
            case R.id.SignOut:
                SignOut();
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult   connectionResult) {

    }

    private void SignIn() {
        Intent intent =  Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(GoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(intent,REQ_CODE);

    }

    private void SignOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(GoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new   ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                UpdateUI(false);
            }
        });

    }

    private void handleResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if(result.isSuccess())
        {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            String name = account.getDisplayName();
            String email = account.getEmail();
            String img_url = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            Name.setText(name);
            Email.setText(email);
            //Glide.vith(this).load(img_url).into(Prof_Pic);
            UpdateUI(true);
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateUI(false);
        }

    }

    private void UpdateUI(boolean isLogin) {
        if(isLogin)
        {
            prof_section.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            SignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            prof_section.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            SignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Im getting no error messages when I run the app

Comment: Welcome to the SO, please go to the LogCat and edit the post to include exception details

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling activitywithresult() function which returns the result, So you will get the result in onActivityResult(). As you are not having any Result handler you are not able to handle the result. You need to add onActivityResult(). If you get the result their, then you have to call your function handleResult() to know whether user is successfully signed in or not.

Just add this code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        String name = account.getDisplayName();
        String email = account.getEmail();
        String img_url = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        Name.setText(name);
        Email.setText(email);
        //Glide.vith(this).load(img_url).into(Prof_Pic);
        UpdateUI(true);

    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        UpdateUI(false);
    }
}
```